# Update UI when Entity Model changes in ViewModel

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework, mvvm, data-binding

I am trying to come up with a good way of implementing the MVVM pattern using Entity-Framework where my entities are my models. My `DataContext` is my viewmodel. This is a small reproduction of the problem.

**View**

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding MyText}" />
```

**ViewModel**:

I have the requirement of needing to navigate record by record from my DB. When a button is clicked in the View a command is sent to the Viewmodel that executes `nextRecord()`. EF does its magic and `_myObject` is the next row/record from the database

```
public class myViewModel: INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private MyEntityObject _myObject;

    public string MyText
    {
        get { return _myObject.MyText; }
        set
        {
            if (_myObject.MyText != value)
            {
                _myObject.MyText = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("MyText");
            }
        }
    }

    private void _nextRecord()
    {
      _myObject = myEntitiesContext.NextRecord() //pseudocode
    }
}
```

**Autogenerated Entity Model**

```
public partial class MyEntityObject
{
     public string MyText { get; set; }
}
```

Since the View has no knowledge of `_myObject` changing, it doesn't update when `_myObject` changes. A few approaches I have thought of.

1. I haven't tested wrapping my entities in a `INotifyPropertyChanged` wrapper class but am wary to do this as I have a lot of entity objects.
2. I could call `OnPropertyChanged("...")` for all properties, but some of my entities have a lot of properties to them, which would be ugly. Possible to use reflection to make it cleaner, but I may have properties that aren't databound.
3. I might be able to defer this to the UI, somehow refreshing the bindings when I click "Next Record", but this breaks MVVM and looks dirty

**How can I get the UI to recognize changes from `_myObject`?**

Comment: How about calling OnPropertyChanged manually from within _nextRecord()?

Comment: @Wiktor `NextRecord` isn't a real method, I just wanted to hide the implementation details for getting the _next_ record since they are unimportant for the problem. But what you said is essentially my 2nd approach. The issue is that it isn't scalable to say, 15-20 properties, where you are in the position of needing to call `OnPropertyChanged` 15-20 times

Comment: So what? This IS what really happens, an object is replaced with another which means that 20 properties change and so that 20 ui components need to refresh. There is no magic behind binding, if somewhere someone doesn't trigger updates, nothing happens.

Comment: @Wiktor I'm not concerned about the performance. It's ugly to see 20 calls to `OnPropertyChanged` and it's something you'll have to remember to update/change whenever the properties change. I'm thinking I could leverage reflection to fix that but haven't tested that yet.

Comment: Probably. The cleanest solution imho is to reflect the fact that view model CHANGES if you switch to another record. This means that there is no INTERNAL, hidden replacement. Instead you recreate the viewmodel upon new model and completely rebind the ui.

Comment: It's worth mentioning that calling `OnPropertyChanged("")` or `OnPropertyChanged(null)` invalidates all properties, so this can be used instead of making a separate call for each property.

Comment: @Adi That depends on your implementation. You might add an answer doing that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As I've mentioned in the comments, calling `OnPropertyChanged("")` or `OnPropertyChanged(null)` invalidates all properties and is equivalent to calling `OnPropertyChanged` for each and every property. This behavior is also [documented here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.propertychanged.aspx):

> The PropertyChanged event can indicate all properties on the object
>   have changed by using either null or String.Empty as the property name
>   in the PropertyChangedEventArgs.

This means that you can simply add a call to `OnPropertyChanged("")` when you update your object to force WPF to reevaluate all bindings to your view model:

```
private void _nextRecord()
{
    _myObject = myEntitiesContext.NextRecord();
    OnPropertyChanged("");
}
```

That being said, I'd still go with @Anand's solution (+1). There's an ongoing debate on whether it's OK or not for the viewmodel to expose the model as a property, and I tend to go with exposing it until you need to introduce some view model specific logic. Most of the time you won't have to and it's not worth the trouble of wrapping model properties.

Comment: I didn't know this could be done -- neat. However, for those who may find this in the future, it is worth noting that it only invalidates properties on the ViewModel, and it will not help you if you want a catch-all for all the bindings on that view, i.e. properties on the Model.

Comment: `OnPropertyChanged` isn't a method provided by INotifyPropertyChanged. You need to provide the implementation for `OnPropertyChanged` in order to claim it handles null and ""

Comment: @Shoe It's just a short way of saying "pass an empty string or null as the property name in the `PropertyChangedEventArgs`". To clarify, it's WPF (the binding event handlers that register to the PropertyChanged event) that knows to requery all properties when the property name is null.

Comment: @Shoe I've also added to my answer a link to MSDN that documents this behavior.

Comment: @Adi I will test this when I get home

Comment: @Adi I used `OnPropertyChanged(null)` and it worked perfectly. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3):

The problem with your code is that when `_myObject` changes the `MyText` property changed event is not fired. A work around would be to create a new property to hold you entity 
and make this property as your `Grid`s `DataContext` in your view as shown below. Now when this line is executed `MyObject = myEntitiesObject.NextRecord()` your view will be notified about the change.

```
public class myViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{

    private MyEntityObject _myObject;

    public MyEntityObject MyObject
    {
        get { return _myObject; }
        set {
            if (_myObject != value)
            {
                _myObject = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("MyObject");
            }
        }
    }


    private void _nextRecord()
    {
      MyObject = myEntitiesObject.NextRecord() //pseudocode
    }
}
```

**View:**

```
    <Grid DataContext="{Binding MyObject}"> 
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding MyText}"/>
    </Grid>
```

Comment: The problem with this is that it's invalidating the ViewModel binding. `MyText` will now be bound to my Model instead of the ViewModel, meaning the whole ViewModel really has no purpose. The other problem is that unless I wrap the entity object in another class to handle `INotifyPropertyChanged`, `MyText` won't be able to respond to changes because, again, now the binding is on the `Model` instead of viewmodel

Comment: @Shoe, your ViewModel should still have a purpose -- it holds commands, does initialization, and other things. Furthermore, if you do want to bind to the ViewModel once your DataContext changed, you can just RelativeSource your binding to the View's DataContext. The only gotchya is that we can't see updates being made to the entity from outside the UI, but that is to be expected if your Model is just a bunch of plain old properties.

Comment: @Guttsy The ViewModel should be an interface for the Model. Binding from the View to the Model directly means we bypass any sort of means of filtering/manipulating that data. Say I wanted to validate the data the users enter into the view. Now It's hard to do that because my business layer was bypassed by the binding.

Comment: @Shoe Well, business rules and validation should be implemented in a proper (reusable) class like a business object, and the business object can understand how to notify that properties have changed. Use your entities only as an interface for getting data in and out of the database. If you are going to do all of that in the ViewModel, you probably aren't really doing MVVM, and you had hope your application doesn't grow in size.

Comment: @Guttsy Sorry, I don't necessarily mean business logic, rather simply validating data that comes through. It's fine to leave the VM in charge of that, but directly binding to the Model means you cannot validate. The only workaround at that point is creating a wrapper class or another layer between the view and model.

Comment: @Shoe I think I'm on the same page as you now. Looks like Adi may have the best solution for you at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

An *extremely simple but not very elegant* solution that I believe would meet needs: upon switching records, set the DataContext to null, then back to the ViewModel.

However, there are arguably more elegant alternatives that require more work to meet all requirements. See Anand's answer for an improvement upon this.

Comment: I explored this, but Events get handled before Commands so the View gets refreshed before the new data in the Viewmodel is set. In the end you end up with a "one off" problem.

Answer (score -1):

The tag in View should have the mode and UpdateSourceTrigger attribute set with values.

Comment: This isn't going to resolve anything. The problem has nothing to do with updating the ViewModel from the View, rather the opposite.